# bash script to send request to url and re-writing the result url

Tags: bash, curl, sed, grep

I'm trying to write bash script that i can send request to website and re-write the result in Url ,, first here the result

```
<id>510</id>
<Title> bla bla </Title>
<Desc />
<ImagePath>http://www.example.com/images/510.jpg</ImagePath>
<Url>http://www.example.com/510_</Url>
<rtl>false</rtl>
<partCount>4</partCount>
```

in above result i would like to change end of the url and the expect it  to be

```
 <Url>http://www.example.com/510_1.zip</Url>
 <Url>http://www.example.com/510_2.zip</Url>
 <Url>http://www.example.com/510_3.zip</Url>
 <Url>http://www.example.com/510_4.zip</Url>
```

based on

```
<partCount>4</partCount>
```

so the

```
<partCount>
```

will have different number and based on that will change the Url path
here my the script

```
for ID in {44..4444};
do
MC=$(cat <<EOM
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
<id>$ID</id>
</OrM>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
EOM
)

for num in {1..4}; do

res=$(curl -sL -d "$MC" "http://www.example.com/ne/eService.asmx" | xmllint  --format - | 
egrep -v 'Desc|rtl' | sed -e "s/_/_$num.zip/g" > tmp.tmp)


cat tmp.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Well then, XSLT to the rescue. Be warned that XSLT will give you eye cancer -- the syntax is horrible, but it's made for this sort of stuff. In any case, the result will be much more robust than any attempt to handle XML with awk or sed.

We'll write some XSLT code (I'll get to that in a moment), put that in a file `urlexplode.xsl`, and then we can use pretty much any XSLT processor under the sun to apply the transformation. For example, with `xalan`:

```
curl -sL -d "$MC" "http://www.example.com/ne/eService.asmx" | xalan -xsl urlexplode.xsl
```

The code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Url">
    <xsl:call-template name="urlexplode">
      <xsl:with-param name="count"   select="ancestor::*/partCount"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="urlstub" select="text()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="urlexplode">
    <xsl:param name="count"  />
    <xsl:param name="urlstub"/>

    <xsl:if test="$count > 0">
      <xsl:call-template name="urlexplode">
        <xsl:with-param name="count"   select="$count - 1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="urlstub" select="$urlstub"  />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <Url><xsl:value-of select="$urlstub"/><xsl:value-of select="$count"/>.zip</Url>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hideous, isn't it? Fortunately, the terror is all syntax; it is much simpler than it looks. Let's go through it in pieces. We have three templates (think of templates in XSLT as you would of functions in other languages). The first is

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

This is an identity template; essentially a catch-all handler that copies everything verbatim that is not matched by another template, applying templates recursively as it goes along. It keeps the XML intact in those places that we do not want to change.

```
  <xsl:template match="Url">
    <xsl:call-template name="urlexplode">
      <xsl:with-param name="count"   select="ancestor::*/partCount"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="urlstub" select="text()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
```

applies to `Url` tags. Instead of copying those verbatim, we pick the `partCount` from the ancestor node and the text inside the `Url` tag, and then we pass the whole thing off to the `urlexplode` template, which is going to do the actual work.

```
  <xsl:template name="urlexplode">
    <xsl:param name="count"  />
    <xsl:param name="urlstub"/>

    <xsl:if test="$count > 0">
      <xsl:call-template name="urlexplode">
        <xsl:with-param name="count"   select="$count - 1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="urlstub" select="$urlstub"  />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <Url><xsl:value-of select="$urlstub"/><xsl:value-of select="$count"/>.zip</Url>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

This one, finally, generates the replacement content for the `Url` node. It calls itself recursively `paramCount` times, then generates a new `Url` node with text composed of the url stub we took from the original node, the current counter, and `.zip`. It also adds a newline (the `&#xa;` stuff), which is not strictly necessary to keep the XML valid but made it more human-readable.

This could be done more simply in XSLT 2.0 (which has a more powerful loop construct), but nothing supports XSLT 2.0, so we're stuck with the old way.

Comment: sound good , but the issue I'm user on the hosting server and xalan not found ,, and cannot install it... i have to use defualts tools such as bash , grep, wget, curl, egrep, sed, tr , etc

Comment: No xalan? What about xsltproc, xmlstarlet, saxon? Perl and cpan, if all else fails? Parsing XML with awk and sed will end in pain; believe me when I say that you want to avoid it.

Comment: yes , all are NOT there except xmllint   as well as  Perl and cpan

Comment: Then my recommendation is to use cpan to install `XML::LibXSLT` to (a subdirectory of) your home directory and use a variation of the script at the bottom of [this article](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/intranet/perlbook/pxml/ch08_03.htm) to process it. Give me a minute to adapt it.

Comment: Ah, damn -- `XML::LibXSLT` requires libxml2 and libxslt, which are probably not installed either (are they?). I need to think a bit.